# Через что лучше реализовать многопоточность для аудио конвертера?

Tags: c#

Читаю вот замечательную статью про многопоточность в C# [раз](https://rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml) и [два](http://rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/CSThreading2.xml) и немного растерялся. Способов её реализации в C# не мало, и через простой `Thread`, и через `BackgroundWorker`, и через `ThreadPool`...

Допустим я хочу сделать аудио конвертер, где пользователь бы мог выбирать количество потоков (до восьми) и который бы имел прогресс бар выполнения. Через что в C# (NET 4.0) принято это реализовывать?

Comment: Начинать можно с `BackgroundWorker`. Потом освоить `Thread`, ну и далее использовать `ThreadPool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread`, `ThreadPoll` и `BackgroundWorker` предназначены для выполнения разных задач.

`ThreadPool` - это способ выполнять в фоне небольшие, короткие задачи.

`Thread` - это класс для ручной работы с потоками.

`BackgroundWorker` - это способ выполнит в фоне *одну* долгую задачу, с отображением ее прогресса на UI.

В вашем случае скорее всего подошли бы зачади - `Task`, запущенные с опцией [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). С использованием [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) для их остановки по требованию и [`Progress<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) для отображения общего прогресса на UI.